# Uri Formatting on Image Source

Tags: windows-runtime, uri

What is wrong with the following uri?

```
bmi.UriSource = (new Uri(@"/Assets/Image.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Where `bmi` is a `BitmapImage`. 
 I have the build action for the image set to Embedded Resource.

Comment: This is WinRT, not WPF, right? If so, you should use proper tags.

Comment: Sorry force of habit, you're correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it;

```
bmi.UriSource = (new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/Logo.png"));
```

And build action set to Content. There's no Relative URI in RT.

Answer (score 0):

WPF needs to use the Resource build action (or Content build action) to use Uris. For binary data (like an image), use Binary.

If you're using a single project for your code (a single dll), you cvan skip the '/MYAPPLICATIONNAME;component/' and just use "Assets/Image.png" as a relative Uri.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting the error`The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri` using `bmi.UriSource = (new Uri(@"/Assets/Image.png", UriKind.Relative));` and build action set to Content.

Comment: Well, then you should use `bmi.UriSource = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(@"/Assets/Image.png");`

Answer (score 0):

Each control or page has a `BaseUri` property which you can use to build the proper uri for assets.

Here is an example:

```
imageIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "Assets/file.gif"));

// Or use the base uri from the imageIcon, same thing
imageIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageIcon.BaseUri, "Assets/file.gif"));
```