# Add Image to Xaml with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, stackpanel

I have a stack panel in my XAML page.

```
 <StackPanel Name="xamlimg" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.column="1">
 </StackPanel>
```

I want to add an image in this `stackpanel` using C# code behind the XAML page.

I have attempted using the structure below, but I can't seem to set the source right.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source= //Image Source here
xamlimg.Children.Add(img);
```

How do I set the image source and add it to the `stackpanel`?

Comment: don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. That's what XAML is for. Learn MVVM.

Comment: `Source` is a `Uri` not a `string`, I am not sure how you got that to compile. You will have to create the proper Uri to the imagefile

Comment: It didn't compile, and I need to create it in the C# code because it does not need to be on the page for every instance, just once a condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign image source using below code:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyNameSpace;images/someimage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this. Got an exception error `The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. `

Comment: Plz look at this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569720/the-given-system-uri-cannot-be-converted-into-a-windows-foundation-uri  and change uri as per above link.

Comment: Also look at this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200542/uri-formatting-on-image-source

Answer (score 0):

it can be many causes, like your img source is inaccurate, the stackpanel is invisible, or it's (parent) size is collaped.

try hand code the img into the xaml, if it worked, then likely u need to look into the container/stackpanel, check it's property about visibility, size, etc.

if it doesn't work, look into the img tag, probably its the source.